# paragraph format in WYSIWYG on a custom theme?

Tags: theme-development

How can i present the same content/paragraph format on my WYSIWYG on my custom wordpress theme?

i never put much thought on how my content shall be presented while im busy doing all the site overall layout, and now im facing this difficulty on trying to reflect the same format paragraph on the post editor in my custom theme.

on WYSIWYG, i have spaces in between my paragraphs, but when i display it on my custom theme, the paragraphs are not separated.

is there a plugin, hooks i can use to use the default wordpress content layout on a custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your theme doesn't have a margin/padding set on the paragraph. Just add the following CSS to the themes style.css and your paragraphs should then be spaced.

```
p {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: i print result as this `<p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>` which are paragraphs, but the displayed result encapsulates them with `<span>` and not in `<p>`

Comment: No idea why you're doing that. You're wrapping the entire content in a single paragraph. Also you only need to use `<?php the_content(); ?>`.